# Why aren't these lines of code returning any result?

Tags: ruby, command

The terminal command:

```
ping -c 1 google.com | grep "time=" | sed -E "s/(.*)time=([.0-9]+) ms/\2/"
```

returns just a number illustrating the ping time with Google.com, without miscellaneous statistics. However if I attempt to extract that output within a Ruby script:

```
detection_medium = `ping -c 1 google.com | grep "time=" | sed -E "s/(.*)time=([.0-9]+) ms/\2/"`
puts detection_medium
```

no output is returned. This syntax works for most other commands, and I am perplexed as to why it isn't working now.

- Why doesn't the code above return the command's output?
- How should I modify it to ensure that it returns the ping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape \2 as \\2. Also, you may want to run .chomp() on the resulting string.